# Array of n function results without a for-loop

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

I have a function `fun` that returns a double. I want to call the function `n` times and store the results in an array:

```
results = zeros(1, n);
for i = 1:n 
    results(i) = fun;
end
```

Can I achieve this without the loop?

`n` is in a range of up to 10,000,000, the runtime of `fun` is almost neglectable.

---

I tried `arrayfun`, but it is actually a lot slower (about 87 times slower):

```
results = arrayfun(@(~) fun, 1:n);
```

May the loop already be the fastest solution? I'd still be interested if this could be done with a one liner.

Comment: Is it always going to return the same value? What is "fun" going to depend on?

Comment: @S.P no, it won't always return the same result. `fun` is an external Java method.

Comment: No other choice that I know of. You will need to loop over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, know that ARRAYFUN basically has a hidden for-loop inside it, so I am not sure you will gain speed. Plus the good old for-loop can sometimes benefit from the Just-in-Time compiler optimizations, so stick with loops :)

If you really want to optimize your code, write your Java function to return an array of n elements at once, rather than calling from MATLAB n times each time returning one value (the bottleneck is the call overhead here).

Comment: Note that it's likely that in a future release, `arrayfun` will become multithreaded.

Comment: @Amro, I guess changing the Java function is the best (fastest) solution. I did not think about it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas: true, I think it already [supports](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/arrayfun.html) running on the GPU

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, and `fun` returns a random/or different double everytime, then the loops is the way to go.